# Will my base be destroyed if I switch maps?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

If I build a base on the Plateau, then move to the Foothills, will my base still be there if I move back to the Plateau? Or will I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base will be destroyed. All of your outposts will be lost. Your enclave relationships will be reset. All looted buildings will be refilled and unexplored.

When you leave a map, all data saved with that map will be lost. You will be compensated with influence and materials for lost relationships and buildings, respectively.

Going to a new map is a completely fresh start, with the exception of characters, inventory, resources, and influence.